# NuSoap returns complexType array not correct?

Tags: php, web-services, wsdl, nusoap, complextype

I have a Webservice WSDL with NuSoap. I use it with CodeIgniter. I have problems with contexttype-array returns. Here is my PHP Code:

```
$this->nusoap_server->wsdl->addComplexType(
                    "getJobStatusByIdsResponse",
                    "complexType",
                    "array",
                    "all",
                    "SOAP-ENC:Array",
                    array(),
                    array(
                        'Job' => array('ref'=>'SOAP-ENC:arrayType','wsdl:arrayType'=>'tns:jobStatusResponse[]', 'minOccurs'=>'1', 'maxOccurs'=>'unbounded')
                    ),
                    'tns:jobStatusResponse'
                );


$this->nusoap_server->wsdl->addComplexType(
                    "getJobStatusByIdsResponse",
                    "complexType",
                    "array",
                    "all",
                    "SOAP-ENC:Array",
                    array(),
                    array(
                        'Job' => array('ref'=>'SOAP-ENC:arrayType','wsdl:arrayType'=>'tns:jobStatusResponse[]', 'minOccurs'=>'1', 'maxOccurs'=>'unbounded')
                    ),
                    'tns:jobStatusResponse'
                );

$this->nusoap_server->register(
                    "getJobStatusByIds",
                    array('getJobStatusByIdsRequest' => 'tns:getJobStatusByIdsRequest'),
                    array('getJobStatusByIdsResponse' => 'tns:getJobStatusByIdsResponse'),
                    false,
                    false,
                    "rpc",
                    "literal",
                    "get JobStatus By Ids"
);

function getJobStatusByIds($data) {
  return array(array('orderId' => '1000', 'jobStatus' => '5'),array('orderId' => '1001', 'jobStatus' => '3'),array('orderId' => '1002', 'jobStatus' => '7'))
}
```

I get this as return:

```
      <ns1:getJobStatusByIdsResponse xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
         <getJobStatusByIdsResponse>
            <item>
               <orderId>1001</orderId>
               <jobStatus>5</jobStatus>
            </item>
            <item>
               <orderId>1002</orderId>
               <jobStatus>3</jobStatus>
            </item>
            <item>
               <orderId>1003</orderId>
               <jobStatus>7</jobStatus>
            </item>
         </getJobStatusByIdsResponse>
      </ns1:getJobStatusByIdsResponse>
```

That not right, isn't it?

How can i get it like this ('Job' instead of 'item'):

```
  <ns1:getJobStatusByIdsResponse xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
     <getJobStatusByIdsResponse>
        <Job>
           <orderId>1001</orderId>
           <jobStatus>5</jobStatus>
        </Job>
        <Job>
           <orderId>1002</orderId>
           <jobStatus>3</jobStatus>
        </Job>
        <Job>
           <orderId>1003</orderId>
           <jobStatus>7</jobStatus>
        </Job>
     </getJobStatusByIdsResponse>
  </ns1:getJobStatusByIdsResponse>
```

Who can me help?
Where can I find more examples for NuSoap?

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps.

Added the code comments to help for those that have trouble remembering the NuSoap params off hand.

```
$this->nusoap_server->register(
                    "getJobStatusByIds",                                                           // method name
                    array('getJobStatusByIdsRequest' => 'tns:getJobStatusByIdsRequest'),           // input params
                    array('getJobStatusByIdsResponse' => 'tns:getJobStatusByIdsResponse'),         // output params
                    false,                                                                         // namespace
                    false,                                                                         // soap action
                    "rpc",                                                                         // style
                    "literal",                                                                     // use
                    "get JobStatus By Ids"                                                         // documentation
);
```

I think the response the definition should look something like this.

```
// Job Status Result Complex Type (output)
$this->nusoap_server->wsdl->addComplexType(
                        "getJobStatusByIdsResponse",
                        "complexType",
                        "struct",
                        "all",
                        "SOAP-ENC:Array",
                        array('Job' => array('orderId' => 'your value here', jobStatus => 'your value here')),
    );
```